# Ionic Refresher doesn't work correctly

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

Iam try to make a ionic 3 demo and i have

```
<ion-refresher (ion-Refresh)="doRefresh($event)" >
    <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
```

and it's function looks like

```
doRefresh(e){
  this.service.getTask()
    .subscribe(
      data => console.log(data),
      err => console.log(err)
     , () => e.complete()
    );
}
```

but it doesn't enter doRefresh function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the you need to remove the `-`

```
<ion-refresher (ion-Refresh)="doRefresh($event)" >
```

should be

```
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)" >
```

**[Ion Refresher](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/)**

Comment: Ops ,my bad.I can't get this or can't even track what is wrong, i guess it may be a migration error or something.